# Azure B2C Sign In Policy Customization - login_hint

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a B2C directory and I have setup the branding for this directory. Apart from this, I have also added a sign in, sign up and a reset policy with custom templates. So far no issues. When I issue a challenge for the sign in policy the page is rendered based on the branding configuration. When I attempt to enter an invalid password, the error template is used.

Now, if the email address is known previously for the current user, I add a login_hint to the authentication properties, so that the user need not enter it in again. The email address gets populated in the email text box as expected, but the branding configuration is not used anymore!

Is this a bug?

PS: I added a sign up or sign in policy and I am currently using this policy to work around this, but would be good to know why this is not working (i.e. the sign in policy)!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug?

Sounds like it but only the B2C product team could confirm this.

> I added a sign up or sign in policy and I am currently using this policy to work around this, but would be good to know why this is not working (i.e. the sign in policy)!

The B2C is in the process of deploying version 2s of their policies.  Can you try the [Sign-in v2 Policy](https://github.com/spottedmahn/azure-ad-b2c-new-portal-updates-2018/issues/3)?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Fair enough.  Please see the upate @Zoe